# fuzzy match and extract strings from a string vector to complete a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, fuzzy-search, fuzzyjoin

I have a liste of french names with some small syntaxic differences.

```
names <- c("Benoit", "Arnoud (son)", "Arnoud", "Arnous", "Archer, Patrice*", "Archer", "Archer (father)", "André" )
```

"Arnoud (son)", "Arnoud", "Arnous" all these names belong to the same family. I would like to be able to create a dataframe object to group individuals by family

```
people1           |people2 |people3  |people4|
"Benoit"          | NA     |NA       |NA
"Arnoud (son)",   |"Arnoud"|"Arnous" | NA
"Archer, Patrice*"|"Archer"| "Archer"|"Archer (father)"
"André"           | NA     | NA      |NA
```

Comment: You can try playing around with different methods in the `stringdistmatrix()`-function from the `stringdist`-package... and go further from there